# Istio Locality-prioritized load balancing not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Unable to configure Locality-prioritized load balancing.
There are two nodes with the labels:

```
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: test-hw1
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: us
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: wdc04
```

```
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: test-hw2
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: eu
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: fra02
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cara
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: cara
spec:
  selector:
    app: cara
  ports:
    - name: http
      appProtocol: http
      targetPort: http
      port: 8000

  topologyKeys:
    - "kubernetes.io/hostname"
    - "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
    - "topology.kubernetes.io/region"
    - "*"
```

DestinationRule:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: cara
spec:
  host: cara.default.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1

    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 2
      baseEjectionTime: 5s
```

If the request comes to test-hw1 node it still sometimes gets routed to test-hw2 node without any reason.

Comment: can you provide LB configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was in the NodePort service that was accepting traffic from outside. Services by default are load-balancing traffic across the pods, so sometimes connections were routed to the other region `istio-ingressgateway` pod.
Simply adding `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` to the service that is accepting traffic from outside on NodePort solved this issue.